# Limit top pair of columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The data I am working with looks like below-

```
category_id   subcategory_id    date       quantities       
    123            45          2020-02-01      500
    123            45          2020-02-13      400
    456            35          2020-05-09      350
    456            35          2020-05-15      250
    456            35          2020-06-18      200
     .
     .
     .
     n such columns
```

Quantities are sorted in descending order
I want to get the data (as seen above) for the first (top) 10 unique pairs of (category_id, subcategory_id). Just like we use limit 10 to get the first 10 records, I want to limit by the top 10 unique pairs of (category_id, subcategory_id) and get the all the data as seen above.

Comment: can you share the source data set and the expected output. Its not very clear what you mean by 10 unique pairs. Does each (category_id,subcategory_id) always have exactly two records ?

Comment: i reread the question again and realized that most likely i answered slightly different one  - which is `select top 10 rows for each unique combination of category and subcategory` - looks like this is not exactly what is being asked. can you please clarify and provide better example including example of expected output. Check How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn) FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id, subcategory_id ORDER BY quantities DESC) rn
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE rn <= 10
```

Another - more BigQuery'ish alternative is below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TopN.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY quantities DESC LIMIT 10) topN
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY category_id, subcategory_id
) t, t.topN
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 rows, each with different `category_id`/`subcategory_id` pairs, then you can use:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category_id, subcategory_id order by quantities desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by quantities desc
limit 10;
```

This gets the first row (by `quantities`) for each id pair and then limits to the 10 largest values.